# single company identify from multiple email address formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant

We are developing a multi-tenant application with self service. Users sign up using their email ids. Each sign up gets assigned to a tenant based on their email id. Tenants are created dynamically based on the network address part of the email id using this simple regex.

```
/.*@(.*)/
```

For example, a user with  user1@amazon.com email signs up, a tenant named `amazon.com` gets created and
assigned to it. When user2@amazon.com signs up he/she will be added to the same tenant. Tenant users get to see each other and share files/content among themselves.

Now it is possible Amazon may have @amazon.co.in emails for employees in their India office.
They may have US prefix, i.e., @us.amazon.com for US employee etc.,

1. Is it feasible/possible, programatically to identify a single company from multiple email formats?. If yes, how do you go about doing it?. Regex examples etc.,
2. Are there any commercial/free services/libraries?

In the current implementation we create a separate tenant for each of amazon.co.in and us.amazon.com and `manually` merge users/data when requested for.

Comment: I'm not sure about a regex, because frankly I'm terrible with them, but I'd imagine you can do something stupid like split it into component parts and then compare against a list of already known tenants i.e. you get "US" "AMAZON" and "CO", and then check your tenant DB, or whatever, and assign appropriately or whatever you wanted to do.  *shrug* Hacky, but a solution until someone more regex inclined responds.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any existing libraries that do what you need, and as far as I can tell, it's not possible to solve this entirely using a regex, however you can narrow things down a bit.

The email specification states that an email of the format user1@example is a valid format, but in practice it's fairly rare out in the open. If you are OK with causing an error (or creating a new tenant that would need to be merged manually) for those cases, you can restrict the matches to everything up to the tld:

```
/^.*@(.*)\.[^\.]+$/
```

This will cover cases like:

- user1@example.com
- user2@example.org

I'm not sure how many labels there are of the type "co" in "co.uk" and "co.in", but if it's a specific set, you could optionally exclude these with following regex (assuming "co" and "ab" are being excluded):

```
/^.*@(.+?)\.(co\.|ab\.)?[^\.]+$/
```

The first capture group would then extract "example" out of the following:

- user1@example.com
- user2@example.org
- user3@example.co.uk
- user4@example.ab.in

After that, you'd probably need to move to a programmatic approach in order to evaluate subdomains such as

- user4@for.example.com

However you would quickly run into trouble with things like:

- user4@for.example.com
- user6@for.example.co.uk
- user6@forexample.com
- user5@for.instance.com

It also gets pretty hairy if you consider that a label might match in several places:

- user6@ab.example.com
- user7@instance.ab.cd

Comment: Thanks. Also what I found is there is no guarantee that example.com and example.org belong to a single company. That leaves us with no reliable way to auto select single a tenant for a sign up from multiple email formats. I was looking for some cloud services.